# Why does assignment persist outside of scope but declaration does not

Tags: c

I was wondering if someone could explain why the following behavior occurs in C. In the following I declare a variable outside the scope and then within an inner scope (the `if`...`else`) the assignment is done, and then the assignment persists past that inner scope.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *str;
    if (argc == 2) {
        str = "Two";
    }
    else {
        str = "Not two";
    }
    my_print(str);
}
```

> Not two

But for a declaration with initialization, it does not live beyond the scope.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2) {
        char* str = "Two";
    }
    else {
        char* str = "Not two";
    }
    my_print(str);
}
```

> ix.c: In function ‘main’: 
> ix.c:15:9: error: expected expression before ‘char’ 
> char* str = "Not two"; 
> .........^~~~
> ix.c:16:14: error: ‘str’ undeclared (first use in this function) 
> my_print(str); 
> ...............^~~

Could someone explain what that's the case? For example, why wouldn't both of the above produce the same output?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're looking for.  The variable is local to the scope where it's declared, which includes all other scopes that may appear within that one.  As long as it is in scope you can read or write it in any part of that scope that you wish, but not outside.  That's just the way the language is designed.

Comment: That (in 2nd example) is called block scope which is supported in C, in 2nd example variable is declared and lives only inside block.

Comment: @NateEldredge actually that's the key point I think I missing: `The variable is local to the scope ***where it's declared***`.

Comment: Yeah, object lifetime, object value, and control flow are all completely separate facets. Otherwise you could never write a program with complex logic at all, except by nesting all your conditions or using recursion (and stateful logic would be absolutely impossible)

Comment: Are you really trying to ask why assignments _do_ persist across block scopes, or why declarations do _not_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example it's not just a "declaration with initialization": you are declaring and initialising inside the inner scope of the `if` branch and the `else` branch.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // SCOPE A
    if (argc == 2) {
        // SCOPE B
        char* str = "Two";
    }
    else {
        // SCOPE C
        char* str = "Not two";
    }
    my_print(str);
}
```

So you have three different scopes. You are trying to use a variable that does not exist in the scope you are using it. To have a code that does not raise a compile-time error you should use this following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // SCOPE A
    if (argc == 2) {
        // SCOPE B
        char* str = "Two";
        my_print(str);
    }
    else {
        // SCOPE C
        char* str = "Not two";
        my_print(str);
    }
}
```

As mentioned: "The variable is local to the scope where it's declared"

Answer (score 3):

Every identifier of a variable has scope determined by the placement of its declaration.

Also each associated sub-statement of if (or if-else) statement forms its own block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of the selection statement.

So in this program

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *str;
    if (argc == 2) {
        str = "Two";
    }
    else {
        str = "Not two";
    }
    my_print(str);
}
```

the variable `str` is declared (and memory is allocated for it that is the variable is defined) in the outer scope of main and is visible in this block and any inner sub-blocks.

String literals have static storage duration. So for example after exiting the block of sub-statement of the if statement

```
    if (argc == 2) {
        str = "Two";
    }
```

the string literal is alive and the pointer stored in the variable `str` is a valid pointer.

In this program

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2) {
        char* str = "Two";
    }
    else {
        char* str = "Not two";
    }
    my_print(str);
}
```

you declared two variables with the name `str` each of which has a block scope that is sub-block of corresponding sub-statement of the if-else statement.

Outside these block scopes the variables `str` are not alive and are invisible. So the compiler issues an error that the name `str` is nor declared in the outer scope of main where it is used in the statement

```
    my_print(str);
```